# Making difficulty function in Hangman game

Tags: python, python-3.x

im new to python and need help with a piece of code I have written. As of current, my program is fully functional, however I cannot get a difficulty function working as intended. I have multiple .txt documents with differing difficulties of words inside them. I would like the user to be able to choose what difficulty they will be playing at. Currently when I attempt to run the program, i get an error message saying "word is not defined". Any help is greatly appreciated

```
import random
print ("WELCOME, YOU ARE PLAYING HANGMAN!")
input("Press Enter to continue...")
def printhangmen(guesses):
    if (guesses == 0):
        print("""
_________
|/        
|              
|                
|                 
|               
|                   
|___                 
""")
    if (guesses == 1): 
        print("""
_________
|/   |      
|              
|                
|                 
|               
|                   
|___                 
""")
    elif (guesses == 2):
        print("""
_________       
|/   |              
|   (_)
|                         
|                       
|                         
|                          
|___                       
""")
    elif (guesses == 3):
        print("""
________               
|/   |                   
|   (_)                  
|    |                     
|    |                    
|                           
|                            
|___                    
""")
    elif (guesses == 4):
        print("""
_________             
|/   |               
|   (_)                   
|   /|                     
|    |                    
|                        
|                          
|___                          
""")
    elif (guesses == 5):
        print("""
_________              
|/   |                     
|   (_)                     
|   /|\                    
|    |                       
|                             
|                            
|___                          
""")
    elif (guesses == 6):
        print("""
________                   
|/   |                         
|   (_)                      
|   /|\                             
|    |                          
|   /                            
|                                  
|___                              
""")

    elif (guesses == 7):
        print("""
________
|/   |     
|   (_)    
|   /|\           
|    |        
|   / \        
|               
|___           
"""" You guessed wrong. The correct word was: " + str(word))

guesses = 8

difficulty = input("""choose your difficulty,
1 = EASY
2 = INTERMEDIATE
3 = HARD
4 = VERY HARD
5 = INSANE""")
print("you have chosen", difficulty)

print("Please begin guessing")

if difficulty == 1:
    (random.choice(open("Level1.txt").read().split()))
elif difficulty == 2:
    (random.choice(open("Level2.txt").read().split()))
elif difficulty == 3:
    (random.choice(open("Level3.txt").read().split()))
elif difficulty == 4:
    (random.choice(open("Level4.txt").read().split()))
elif difficulty == 5:
    (random.choice(open("Level5.txt").read().split()))

word = (random.choice(open("Level"(difficulty).txt).read().split()))

guess_word = ['_' for x in word]
def checkLetter(letter, word, guess_word):
    for c in word:
            if c == letter:
                    guess_word[word.index(c)] = c                 

while '_' in guess_word and guesses > 0:
    print(guess_word)
    guess = input('Letter: ')

    if guess in word:
                    print("correct letter")
    else:
                    print("incorrect")
                    guesses -= 1
                    print (guesses," guesses left")
                    printhangmen(8-guesses)                    

    checkLetter(guess, word, guess_word)

else:
    print("congrats, you won. If you would like to proceed to the next level, please press enter")
    input()
```

Comment: `input()` returns a string, so the following `if difficulty == 1:` type statements should be changed to `if difficulty == "1":`.

Comment: You need to format your code. There is an else statement that I can't find the if statement.

Then you have in the function if == 0 then if == 1 then elif, why not elif == 1?

Comment: Thanks dude. Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @martineau nice catch

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is that you are trying to read the target file twice, and you never close it the first time.  Consider just reading the input file once:

```
while True:
    difficulty = int(input("""choose your difficulty,
    1 = EASY
    2 = INTERMEDIATE
    3 = HARD
    4 = VERY HARD
    5 = INSANE"""))

    if difficulty >= 1 and difficult <= 5:
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a difficulty level of 1 to 5")

word = random.choice(open("Level"(difficulty).txt).read().split())
```

Also, `input()` returns a string, so if you want to treat the `difficulty` as an integer, then cast the result from `input()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read a word twice. Replace the line in the if statement by:
`word=(random.choice(open("Level1.txt").read().split()))`
Don't forget to declare 'word' before the if-elif block. And remove the line at the end of if statements. 
`word = (random.choice(open("Level"(difficulty).txt).read().split()))`

Also, treat input as string as suggested in other answers.
This should work according to me

Answer (score 0):

Here you try to append the difficulty to the "Level" string.

```
word = (random.choice(open("Level"(difficulty).txt).read().split()))
```

you could try something like this

```
word = (random.choice(open("Level{0}.txt".format(difficulty)).read().split()))
```

to actually get the filename you expect.

With this you also can remove the

```
if difficulty == X:
```

parts, but you need to take care to check if the file you try to open with the users input really exists.

And you also need to take a look at your checkLetter methode, because the line

```
guess_word[word.index(c)] = c
```

will only change the first occurence of the correct letter in the guess_word string (maybe multiple times if the letter occurs more than once). You need to get the positions of every occurance of the correct letter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, however the program is not correctly using the "word" and if I do enter the number I entered at the start it will direct me to my index statement as you talked about and displays the error, "Substring not located". Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: What does your code look like right now? Maybe edit your question to reflext your new problem